# Segmentation fault when connecting to MySQL

Tags: c++, mysql, linux, segmentation-fault, mysql-connector

I have this code in a big project that makes a connection to a MySQL database, and does not work:

```
boost::shared_ptr<sql::Connection> connection;

sql::Driver *driver = get_driver_instance();
assert(driver != 0);

std::string server = "servname", user = "pietro", password = "abc";

try
{
    connection.reset(driver->connect(server, user, password));
    assert(connection != 0);

    if(connection->isClosed() == false)     // <-- segmentation fault
    {
    }

}
```

I get a segmentation fault where indicated (all parameters are valid).
However, this same code works in a test project.

Going into the `sql::Connection::isClosed()` member function with a debugger, I obtain no information about the possible cause; here is where I get:

> mysql-connector-c++-1.0.5/driver/mysql_connection.cpp - line 430

```
/* {{{ MySQL_Connection::checkClosed() -I- */
void
MySQL_Connection::checkClosed()
{
    CPP_ENTER_WL(intern->logger, "MySQL_Connection::checkClosed");
    if (!intern->is_valid) {
        throw sql::SQLException("Connection has been closed");
    }
}
```

This `checkClosed()` function is successfully executed seven times from `connection.reset()` just before. The value of the "`intern`" pointer does not change and is not null at this stage.

When I check if the connection is closed, the `checkClosed()` function is run again. Now the "`intern`" pointer value is 0x8, a location I cannot access.

Here I get a `SIGSEGV`, segmentation fault.

Let me know if you would like the disassembled code...

*Platform:*
MySQL 5.x
MySQL Connector/C++ 1.0.5
Linux - OpenSuse 11.4

---

P.S.:
I noticed that all the `shared_ptr`'s member functions work as expected:

```
connection.get();          // = 0x8fb4a0
connection.use_count();    // = 1
connection.unique();       // = 1
```

while all the calls done on the pointed object cause the segmentation fault (SIGABRT):

```
connection->getClientInfo();
connection->isClosed();
```

Comment: Which member variable is defined before 'intern'? The mistake must be somewhere else. The code you showed is not the problem.

Comment: All I can see before 'intern' is that debugging macro which is disabled. I reported all the debugging steps I did, so there is not other code executed in the middle.

Comment: Why do you call reset through the . operator, and isClosed through the -> operator?  Is this problem due to some funky behaviour from shared_ptr or is it merely a typo in this question?

Comment: Did you run `valgrind` on your entire program? Perhaps there is a memory leak (or overflow) not directly related to MySQL, but just triggering the SIGSEGV in the MySQL connector...

Comment: @James: because `reset()` is a member function of the `shared_ptr` class, while `isClosed()` is a member function of `sql::Connection`, to which the shared pointer points to.

Comment: Ah, ok.  So why not put a memory breakpoint on the intern pointer and see exactly when it changes from 'valid' to 0x08?

Answer (score 0):

either your connection deleted, or you have memory corruption. use valgrind to find answer